# Regex Mystery - Can you help me add these options?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, markdown

## The problem

My regex below for a PHP preg_replace works great

```
 '|(?<!</h2>)\s*\n(?!<h2>)|'
```

However I would much rather the 'h2' part be a section which searches for any of 'h2|p|li|div' etc, just whatever it can find out of the choices I give it.

I have tried all sorts like

```
'|(?<!</(?:h2|p|li|div)>)\s*\n(?!<(?:h2|p|li|div)>)|'
```

But it just will not seem to work.

This would be a great help if anyone can point me in the correct direction as I am working this out as an alternative to a problem I posted yesterday.

## Extra notes

My aim for the code BTW is to FIND ALL LINE BREAKS (\n) that DO NOT have a /h2 or /p etc  BEFORE the line break and DO NOT have a h2 or p etc AFTER the linebreak. So....

```
example\n                        <- find this
example\n                        <- find this
example\n                        <- not this (as <h2> next starts line)
<h2>example\n                    <- find this
example</h2>\n                   <- not this (as </h2> ends this line)
example\n                        <- find this
```

Many many thanks,

Comment: Do you parse .txt file, or something else?

Comment: The second regex you tried will not work simply because you are using the `|` character as your delimeter which also means `OR` in regex. This will work for the first one only because you aren't actually using `|` in the pattern. Replace the first and last `|` with a different delimeter (`~` would work).

Comment: I am new to regex, so apologies for not recognising this error.
Unfortunately however now a new error message is:
"Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 22" -- does a lookbehind need to be a fixed lengh meaning I cannot use multiple block types?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use this:

```
~<(h2|p|li|div)([^\>]+)?>([^\<]+)?</(h2|p|li|div)>~
```

That accounts for stuff like `class="xyz"` in the opening tag.

This will fix the regex you provided, but if you want to accomplish what you described at the bottom of your question, you'll probably need something more complicated.